# Formula for infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, recursion, products

I have the following sequence:

$$\begin{align}x_1&=2\\
x_n&=x_{n-1}(ab+a)-1\end{align}$$

$a$ and $b$ are positive numbers.

What would be the formula for $x_n$ that does not refer to $x_{n-1}$?

Comment: I didn't post any attempts because I don't know what to do...

Comment: do you need an explicit formula?

Comment: Yes, one that does not refer to $x_{n−1}$

Comment: If you write $c=ab+a$ then you have $x_1=2,x_2=2c,x_3=2c^2,x_4=2c^3$. Do you see the pattern?

Comment: Yea the $-1$ was lost. Restored it.

Comment: Incidentally, the term for this is a *closed form*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c=ab+a$ to make the numbers nicer; then $x_1 = 2$ and $x_n = c x_{n-1} - 1$.

Then $x_2 = 2c-1, x_3 = 2c^2-c-1, x_4 = 2c^3-c^2-c-1$.

I formulate an inductive hypothesis! $x_i = 2c^{i-1} - c^{i-2} - \dots - c - 1$.

This is easy to prove inductively. You can also simplify it a bit if you like, noting that the $- c^{i-2} - \dots - c - 1$ terms are the [negation of a] sum of finitely many terms of a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$x_n = ux_{n-1}+v
$.

If $u=1$,
this is
$x_n = x_{n-1}+v
$,
so
$x_n = x_0+nv$.

From now on,
I will assume that
$u \ne 1$.

I now apply a standard trick
and divide by
$u^{n}$.
This becomes
$\dfrac{x_n}{u^n}
= \dfrac{x_{n-1}}{u^{n-1}}+\dfrac{v}{u^n}
$.

Now, let
$y_n
= \dfrac{x_n}{u^n}
$.
This becomes
$y_n
= y_{n-1}+\dfrac{v}{u^n}
$,
or
$y_n- y_{n-1}=\dfrac{v}{u^n}
$.

Summing this from
$1$ to $m-1$,
we get

$\begin{array}\\
y_m-y_0
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} (y_n- y_{n-1})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \dfrac{v}{u^n}\\
&=v\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} (1/u)^n\\
&=v\dfrac{1/u-1/u^m}{1-1/u}\\
\text{or}\\
\dfrac{x_m}{u^m}-x_0
&=v\dfrac{1/u-1/u^m}{1-1/u}\\
&=v\dfrac{1-1/u^{m-1}}{u-1}\\
\text{or}\\
x_m
&=x_0u^m+v\dfrac{u^m-u}{u-1}\\
&=u^m(x_0+\dfrac{v}{u-1})-\dfrac{uv}{u-1}\\
\end{array}
$